# updating mysql by id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and after looking on the web for the last hour I couldn't find out what was wrong with my code so I come to you. Im trying to have a place to update my data collected from a from. I get this error. Undefined index: id in /Users/mm1/Desktop/php/backend form/edit_ac.php on line 12. Here is what I have so far. Can someone please help..

```
<?php require("database.php"); ?>
<?php require("functions.php"); ?>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$id= mysql_prep($_GET['id']);
$last= mysql_prep($_POST['last']);
$first= mysql_prep($_POST['first']);


// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET first='{$first}', last='{$last}' WHERE id='{$id}'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='edit_info.php'>View result</a>";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Here is the form (I know it all isn't complete I'm just trying to get it to work first.)

```
<?php require("database.php"); ?>


<?php // Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>


<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit_ac.php">
<table width="700" border="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="center"><h3>PARTICIPANT IDENTIFICATION</h3></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="218">First</td>
    <td width="456"><input name="first" type="text" maxlength="50" id="first" value="<? echo $rows['first']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td width="218">Last</td>
    <td width="456"><input name="last" type="text" maxlength="50" id="last" value="<? echo $rows['last']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td width="218">Middles</td>
    <td width="456"><input name="middle" type="text" maxlength="50" id="middle" value="<? echo $rows['middle']; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Address</td>
    <td><input name="address" type="text" maxlength="50" id="address" value="<? echo $rows['address']; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>City</td>
    <td><input name="city" type="text" maxlength="50" id="city" value="<? echo $rows['city']; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>State</td>
    <td><input name="state" type="text" maxlength="15" id="state"  value="<? echo $rows['state']; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Zip</td>
    <td><input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="15" id="zip" value="<? echo $rows['zip']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Home Phone</td>
    <td><input name="home_phone" type="text" id="home_phone" value="<? echo $rows['home_phone']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Daytime Phone</td>
    <td><input name="daytime_phone" type="text" id="daytime_phone" value="<? echo $rows['daytime_phone']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Email Address</td>
    <td><input name="email_address" type="text" id="email_address" value="<? echo $rows['email_address']; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Birthday</td>
    <td><input name="month" type="text" id="month" size="3" maxlength="2" value=""/> / <input name="day" type="text" id="day" size="3" maxlength="2" value=""/> / <input name="year" type="text" id="year" size="5" maxlength="4"  value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Social Security Number</td>
    <td><input name="ss_1" type="text" id="ss_1" size="5" maxlength="3" value=""/> - <input name="ss_2" type="text" id="ss_2" size="5" maxlength="2"  value=""/> - <input name="ss_3" type="text" id="ss_3" size="5" maxlength="4" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="center"><h3>PHOTO IDENTIFICATION </h3></td>
    </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td>Type of ID</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="type_of_id" id="type_of_id" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>ID Number</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="id_number" id="id_number" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Issuing Jurisdiction</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="issuing_state" id="issuing_state"  value=""/></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Expiration Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="expiration_date" id="expiration_date" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Issue Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="issue_date" id="issue_date" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="center"><h3>ESTABLISHING YOUR ACCOUNT</h3></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
  <td colspan="2" class="center">Designate Account Type</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  Acount Type
  </td>
  <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="traditional" value="1" id="traditional" />
        Traditional</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="roth" value="1" id="roth" />
       Roth</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sep" value="1" id="sep" />
        SEP</label>
      <br />
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="simple" value="1" id="simple" />
        SIMPLE</label>
      <br /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" class="center">Fund Your Account</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input name="rollover" type="radio" value="1" id="rollover" />I will rollover cash from an existing IRA or qualified retirement plan
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Prior Custodian Plan Name</td>
  <td><input name="prior_plan_name" type="text" maxlength="50" id="prior_plan_name" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Expected Rollover Amount</td>
  <td><input name="rollover_amount" type="text" maxlength="50" id="rollover_amount" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input name="transfer" type="radio" value="1"  id="transfer" />    I will transfer assets from another IRA and have attached a TRANSFER AUTHORIZATION form </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input name="contribution" type="radio" value="1"  id="contribution"/>    I have attached a contribution check as follows</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>IRA Cash Contribution for the Year</td>
  <td><input name="cash_contributions_1" type="text" id="cash_contributions_1" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>in the amount of</td>
  <td><input name="amount_1" type="text" id="amount_1" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>IRA Cash Contribution for the Year</td>
  <td><input name="cash_contributions_2" type="text" id="cash_contributions_2" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>in the amount of</td>
  <td><input name="amount_2" type="text" id="amount_2" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Employer OR Employee (circle one) SEP/SIMPLE Contribution for the Year</td>
  <td><input name="employer_contributions" type="text" id="employer_contributions" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>in the amount of</td>
  <td><input name="amount_3" type="text" id="amount_3" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
    <td style="text-align:right"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

</table>
<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: are you sure you pass the ID via $_GET and not with $_POST ?

Comment: Are you sure there is an id field?, post the form that calls your script

Comment: Show the html for your get and posts

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php With just a few changes you can update to the mysqli syntax. mysql is going away. Example 1 at this link shows the differences between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the id into the form as a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php print $rows['id'] ?>">
```

Comment: Glad to help. I can see you are a new member, so I will mention that it is customary to accept an answer that solves your question. It is like a little check mark on the side of the answer. Having a high acceptance ratio helps you get future answers, and gives the answerer a rep bonus for participating in the site.

Answer (score 0):

An undefined index simply means that the index of a certain array doesn't exist. So in this case `$_GET` has not index of `id`.

Perhaps you should be checking if the variables are set before anything.

```
if(!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_POST['last']) && !empty($_POST['first'])){
    // other code
}
```

You may also be using the wrong superglobal, like GeoPhoenix said, are you sure it's not `$_POST['id']` you're looking for?

Comment: Define: "Still not working" Maybe you're passing the wrong field name.

Comment: Show the html page for your get and posts.

Comment: It isnt updating the fields. Im sure it has something to do with not properly defining my id.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't including the parameters in the call to the page you are getting errors because you turned error reporting all the way up in the first few lines:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Often PHP (and therefore PHP tutorials) assume a lower setting where PHP will either throw a warning or ignore index errors on arrays. Therefore when you hit:

```
$id= mysql_prep($_GET['id']);
$last= mysql_prep($_POST['last']);
$first= mysql_prep($_POST['first']);
```

It throws an error, but your references might assume it fails quietly.

Your form appears to provide the ID number in the `id_number` instead of just `id`.  So switching to `$id=mysql_prep($_GET['id_number']);` is likely to get more effective results.

Since you are new to PHP I also strongly suggest changing your PHP library away from the old mysql lib to either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Changes people are suggesting will likley get you the results you expect but not fix the multiple [SQL Injection vulnerabilities](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) this script has.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your form that has the name "id".

If your using $_get['id'] you must have a link or submit button that tranfers to a url that looks like this.

```
<a href="phpfile.php?id=PUT_VALUE_HERE>
```

Notice the url has the variable name id after the question mark and you tell what the variable is after the =.

Otherwise if your not going to put your variable in a url. You use $_POST['id'].
In order for $_POST['id'] to work you need an input in your form that has the name attribute set to id. For example

```
<input name="id" type="text">
```

I do not see anything in your form with a name attribute set to "id".